# how to add image to toast in react native,is it possible?

Tags: react-native, toast

import Toast from 'react-native-View-Toast'

here i am trying to add an image to toast to see how it works and i want to know types of toast libraries
and there uses in react-native

Comment: Hello @Sudhakar Reddy,
Actually you can create your own custom Toast very easily with Image support. Actually you do not need to use `Native` Toast for this. Simply create your own library or even fork some of the `Toast library` and add a Image support. It is totally doable.

Comment: import Toast from 'react-native-view-toast'
 
// show
this.toast = Toast.show(message, {
            duration: Toast.durations.Long,
            position: Toast.positions.BOTTOM,
            shadow: false,
            animation: true,
            view: () => (
                <View style={{alignItems: 'center', marginBottom: 10}}>
                    <Image source={require('../img/bugaoxing.png')} style={{height: 44, width: 44}} />
                </View>
            )
        })
        
// hide
Toast.hide(this.toast)            suggest edits to help in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the setView() method to add the imageview or any view to the Toast notification, use this method to customize the Toast as needed.

Here i have created a Custom layout file to be inflated into the Toast notification, and then i have used this layout in Toast by using setView() method.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
  android:background="@android:color/white">

    <TextView
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:text="PM is here"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black">
    </TextView>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/new_logo"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1">
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:text="This is the demo of Custom Toast Notification"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black">
    </TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

for the libraries you can check at
[openbase.io](https://openbase.io/packages/top-react-native-toast-libraries)

Comment: can you explain clearly with example without any hesitate